# javascript/jquery - Hide element in parent tab controlled from pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, popup, window

is that possible in jquery? that I will going to have a popup window. Assuming that my button/controller is in my pop up window and I want to hide element that is located in the parent window . Can a pop window touch or manipulate the parent elements? How? please help

Or like if I close the popup some element will be hidden in the parent window'

please help

Comment: [Tutorial](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Open-PopUps-and-exchange-data-between-parent-page-and-PopUp-using-JavaScript.aspx) for parent<->pop up communication :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes..

if using dialog popup

```
$('#idUWant').hide();
```

if iframe use parent

```
parent.find('#idUWant').hide();
```

if window

```
window.opener.find('#idUWant').hide();
```

Comment: Or like if I close the popup some element will be hidden in the parent window'

Comment: You can try `yourPopUp.document.body.onbeforeunload = function () { alert("closed") };`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the window.opener from the popup:

```
 window.opener.jQuery("#YourSelector");
```